# If we execute a symbolic link python script, can we print the path of the real file?

Tags: python

If I execute a python script which is actually a symbolic link linked to the real script from somewhere else, is there anyway we can print the location of the real script?

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, if you don't want to use argv

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
print os.path.realpath(__file__)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys

print os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0])
```